# What are the limitations of WCF HTTPBinding?

Tags: c#, wcf, thrift, language-interoperability

I am developing a .NET application (say A) which will talk to other .NET applications (say B). The application A is going to be consumed by a Java application (say X). I am currently using Apache Thrift. Thrift is great except for the basic support for OOPS features (such as overloading and inheritance). Of course, we can customize the Thrift compiler in the way we want as it is a open source technology.

One of my friend suggested to use WCF for application A and to use WSHttpBinding. Does WCF service when using Basic/WSHtppBinding has any limitations other limitations to go ahead with that? I guess the limitations of web service are applicable for the above stated way of hosting. Please guide me in this.

Comment: See binding comparison here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on a few projects where we have had to integrate WCF and Java.  I have always ended up going for the BasicHttpBinding as that has allowed the two technologies to communicate with the least amount of friction.  You lose a lot by using BasicHttpBinding over WsHttpBinding but that has not been an issue with the projects I have worked on.  You are going to have to make the call between ease of use (BasicHttpBinding) and support for more/newer standards (WsHttpBinding).

Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36396/Difference-between-BasicHttpBinding-and-WsHttpBind

Comment: Thanks @pkidza. My concern is about session management and all. Do we need to make a compromise on that? I will check the link you sent.

Comment: I don't think you do need to compromise as WCF supports WS-ReliableMessaging as well as a number of other ways for keeping track of sessions:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx.  The context bindings might also be something to look into.  That said I have never had to do this and so can't answer from practical experience.

Answer (score -1):

Limitations of WCF are :
ASP.NET 4.0
Visual studio 2010
IIS 7.5
MS SQL server 2008 R2